# Get impersonated user name

Tags: .net, impersonation

I have a class that needs to know name of a user currently in effect. `Environment.UserName` or `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` is for that. But when impersonation is enabled, they return `LocalUser` name not the `ImpersonatedUser` name.

How to get name of currently impersonated user?

The app is C# console application, I know that impersonation is in effect since I get priviledges of `ImpersonatedUser`. Sure I can make impersonation code save impersonated username to some global variable, but it would be wrong.

**UPDATE:**

Impersonation code:

```
if (LogonUser(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS/*=9*/, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
{
  if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
  {
    WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
    _impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();

    // WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name equals "LocalUser" 
    // while userName equals "ImpersonatedUser"
    ...
```

I have control over impersonation code, but I would prefer to keep it independant from other parts of solution.

Comment: See the demo code for [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx) - it looks like GetCurrent().Name should work

Comment: For some reason it's not working for me, see question update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it appears that problem was in propert impersonalization logon type.

If in impersonalization code replace `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` (9) with `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` (2) everything works fine - `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` and `Environment.UserName` both return ImpersonatedUser as expected.

Comment: zzandy you have a misunderstanding. LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS does not really "impersonate" the user, therefore the WindowsIdentity.Name is being reported correctly. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Just this (instance member)

```
WindowsIdentity.Name
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx

You don't even have to have called Impersonate().

#### EDIT

Without access or knowledge of the impersonation,

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(false).Name
(same as)
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

should work.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x22bbxz6.aspx

> false to return the WindowsIdentity of the thread if it is impersonating or the WindowsIdentity of the process if the thread is not currently impersonating.

---

If you were using LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, bear in mind that (http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/logonuser-issues-t1385578.html) the logged in context remains unchanged while a second token is created for remote resources - this is why your WindowsIdentity.Name remains unchanged - in effect it is still correct, because you have not **actually** impersonated the identity, all you have is a token to access resources as the secondary identity while the entire program/thread is still running under the `original` Windows Identity.

Comment: WindowsIdentity does not provide any static properties and WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name return LocalUser's name.

Comment: I thought you were controlling the impersonation

Comment: I am controlling the impersonation but it happens in different module than one that needs username and I'd like to keep them separated.

Comment: Is it possible to get the name of a user 'kinda' impersonaned with LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS?