# Accessing Virtual Disk Service on remote machine - UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: windows, com, windows-services, credentials

I try to access a virtual disk service (VDS) on a remote machine. After solving some issues that were related to missing Windows Firewall rules (RPC not available) I`m running into an UnauthorizedAccessException (E_ACCESSDENIED) when querying the service.

This is my code:

```
        // Create the service loader
        VdsServiceLoader loaderClass = new VdsServiceLoader();
        IVdsServiceLoader loader = (IVdsServiceLoader)loaderClass;            
        Console.WriteLine("Got Loader");

        // Load the vds service
        try
        {
            loader.LoadService(<Hostname>, out service);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // E_ACCESSDENIED
            Console.WriteLine("Need admin rights");
            return;
        }
```

If I access the local service this Exception is thrown when I didn't execute with admin rights. If I excecute with admin rights, everything is fine and I get the local VDS information without problems.

I think I`ve to specify a Username/Password somewhere to access the service, but I don't know where. Or grant access rights to this service on the remote machine.

I also tried the suggested ImpersonateUser like this

```
if (ImpersonationAPI.LogonUser(pUsername, pDomain, pPassword, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, ref token) != 0)
{
    if (ImpersonationAPI.DuplicateToken(token, SecurityImpersonationLevel.SecurityImpersonation, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
    {
         tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
         LoadUserProfile(tokenDuplicate, pUsername);
         m_ImpersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
         ...
     }
}
```

I also tried the flags LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT and LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE.

Both machines running Win 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log on to the remote machine and impersonate a user with appropriate rights there. For this, use `LogonUser` with `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` logon type, construct a Windows identity with the resulting token and impersonate it. See e.g. this question [Get impersonated user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153161/get-impersonated-user-name) for a sample.

Comment: I found this: Initializing DCOM security and impersonating ...<are different> the reason for this is that DCOM
security is initialized by the CLR (by calling CoInitializeSecurity) to use
the process credentials by default. So the reason why it fails is because
the default process security blanket is used when calling into COM/DCOM, If
you wan't to apply different security setings for the process you'll have to
call CoInitializeSecurity very early in the process (at least before your
first call into COM/DCOM).

Comment: i tried your suggestion again because the app now runs as service under nt-authority\system-account. I impersonated with the "new credentials" flag (also used other flags as test) and specified credentials of an admin user. i still get an E_ACCESSDENIED when trying to connect to the service